# How to 'multitype' fixed-order, fixed-length list in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, typing

In my Flutter project, I have enabled the `lint` package. Somewhere in my code, I have a map `Map<String, List<dynamic>> options = ...;`. The List is typed as dynamic, but in fact it is always a non-growable, length 2 list `[String, IconData]`. I use map as follows:

```
options.entries
    .map((e) => SwitchListTile(
          title: Text(e.value[0].toString()),
          secondary: Icon(e.value[1]),
          value: notificationSettings[e.key],
          onChanged: (bool value) => onNotificationChanged(topic: e.key, enabled: value),
        ))
    .toList());
```

I.e. the `String` in the list is the title of the listTile, the `IconData` is the icon to show, and the map keys are given to the `notificationSettings` to fetch the current setting, as well as to the `onNotificationChanged` handler that updates the setting.

The linter says that I shouldn't use `dynamic` variables at the places where I used `e.value[i]`, so I was wondering if a non-growable, fixed-type list could be typed explicitly, e.g. by writing something like `List<String, IconData>`. I have tried some intuitive syntaxes, but none work, and I can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does not support tuples right now but it is being discussed.

For now, you should either create a `class` specific for your pair of data like this (please give it a better name which describes the purpose :) ):

```
class StringIconDataRelation {
  final String string;
  final IconData iconData;

  const StringIconDataRelation(this.string, this.iconData);
}
```

Alternative, you can make a generic `Pair` class which can be used in your project:

```
class Pair<T1, T2> {
  final T1 a;
  final T2 b;
  
  const Pair(this.a, this.b);
}
```

You can then have your `options` to have the type `Map<String, Pair<String, IconData>>`.

In general, it is often recommended to create specific classes for relations since it can be made the code more clear and you can implement other relevant methods. But if it is for simple stuff, it is often not a problem to use a `Pair` class.

You can also find a lot of packages on pub.dev which gives you tuples of different dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the examples! This should work fine for my use case. I'll keep my eyes open for Dart tuple support too.